# MCE Hardware issue causes reboot for AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7

Tags: server, reboot, amd-ryzen

I'm experiencing this issue for the year. Tried to figure out and fix, but couldn't find any good solution, updates didn't help (BIOS now is latest, OS is latest, Kernel - one of the latest). Tried to google around for the issue, tried to parse the MCE but couldn't get any useful information from there. Maybe you can give me some more ideas how can I fix this.

So, what I have is:

Kernel: `5.4.0-73-generic`

OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Part of the information about processor:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 21
model           : 101
model name      : AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x600611a
cpu MHz         : 2169.010
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmp
erf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core 
perfctr_nb bpext ptsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic vgif overflow_recov
bugs            : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips        : 6986.87
TLB size        : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro acc_power [13]
```

And here is the error I see in `dmesg` logs after reboot:

```
[    0.257771] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.257773] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 2: be0000000012010a
[    0.257776] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR f780 MISC d01a000100000000 
[    0.257778] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:660f51 TIME 1622490129 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 600611a
[    0.257780] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.257781] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: b200001000020c0f
[    0.257782] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 
[    0.257783] kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:660f51 TIME 1622490129 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 600611a
[    2.851627] kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
```

This reboot happens pretty frequently (once a day) without any load on the PC and I have a media server running there and file storage, and it's not acceptable.

**EDIT 1:**

**free -h**:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.3Gi       1.2Gi       123Mi        15Mi       6.0Gi       5.8Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

**sysctl vm.swappiness**:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

**sudo lshw -C memory**:

```
  *-firmware                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       description: BIOS                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
       physical id: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       version: F53                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       date: 01/05/2021                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
       size: 64KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       capacity: 16MiB                  
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi                                                                        
  *-memory            
       description: System Memory 
       physical id: 1d        
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB           
     *-bank:0             
          description: [empty]                                                                                         
          product: Unknown                                                                                             
          vendor: Unknown                  
          physical id: 0      
          serial: FFFFFFFF                    
          slot: DIMM 0                                     
     *-bank:1                          
          description: [empty]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          product: Unknown                
          vendor: Unknown             
          physical id: 1                                                                                               
          serial: FFFFFFFF                    
          slot: DIMM 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     *-bank:2                               
          description: [empty]                       
          product: Unknown                          
          vendor: Unknown                  
          physical id: 2                                   
          serial: FFFFFFFF                         
          slot: DIMM 0                                     
     *-bank:3                          
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2132 MHz (0.5 ns)                                                
          product: CMK8GX4M1D3000C16
          vendor: Unknown             
          physical id: 3                                                                                               
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1                                                                                                 
          size: 8GiB         
          width: 64 bits               
          clock: 2132MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0           
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 1f
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 320KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       capacity: 320KiB                                                                                                
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)       
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified                                                                         
       configuration: level=1                                       
  *-cache:1                                                         
       description: L2 cache                                        
       physical id: 20                                              
       slot: L2 - Cache                                             
       size: 2MiB                                                   
       capacity: 2MiB                                               
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)                                          
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified                                                                         
       configuration: level=2
```

Results of memtest86 (couldn't download HTML report from the USB stick, so adding screens):
[memtest_page_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYXhe.jpg)
[memtest_page_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OooBI.jpg)

**EDIT 2:**

And here is the motherboard information (rev 1.1):

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: A320M-H-CF
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number: Default string
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

And some more info on the memory installation (maybe will be helpful):

```
Handle 0x001D, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 128 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x001C
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001D
    Error Information Handle: 0x0022
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: FFFFFFFF
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: None
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001D
    Error Information Handle: 0x0024
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: FFFFFFFF
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: None
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001D
    Error Information Handle: 0x0026
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: FFFFFFFF
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: None
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001D
    Error Information Handle: 0x0028
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2132 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: CMK8GX4M1D3000C16   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2132 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 3, Hex 0x9E
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

**EDIT 3:**

After memtests and swap enablaed here is result of asked commands in comments:

*free -h*

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.3Gi       988Mi       3.7Gi        15Mi       2.6Gi       6.1Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

*swapon -s*

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        4194300 0   -2
```

Could you please suggest in which direction should I look for the solution?

Comment: You may have a CPU or memory problem. AMD processors are very fussy about memory. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Hi @heynnema , Thanks for your attention to this topic. I have updated the question and added results of memtest.

Comment: Tell me the EXACT make/model of your motherboard. I need to check the BIOS, and confirm your memory installation. How long have you had this configuration, and when did the problem begin?

Comment: @heynnema, added description of motherborad + revision number and some information on the memory slots (the last one is in use and shows some useful information). I have this configuration for at least 6month and this issue appears once per few days in general. So, I would even say it's basic installation I had since beginning and nothing changed inside.

Comment: Although your data didn't indicate the revision of your motherboard, I suspect you have revision 1.x. See https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-H-rev-1x#kf If you look at the CPU and memory docs, it doesn't look like your 8G RAM model # is on the supported list. See https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-a320m-h_bristol.pdf

Comment: And oh... I just noticed... you also have a swap problem. Edit your question and show me `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

**SWAP**

You have a swap problem.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.3Gi       1.2Gi       123Mi        15Mi       6.0Gi       5.8Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

**Note**: Edit your question and show me `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Let's confirm/create a 4G /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Memory**

Although your data didn't indicate the revision of your motherboard, I suspect you have revision 1.x. See https://gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-H-rev-1x#kf If you look at the CPU and memory docs, it doesn't look like your 8G RAM Corsair model # CMK8GX4M1D3000C16 is on the supported list. See https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-a320m-h_bristol.pdf

**Update #1:**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

If it fails, move the DIMM from slot DDR4_B1 to slot DDR4_A1 and rerun memtest.

If it fails again, replace the DIMM.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try one by one. 

**swap** - I don't have it enabled from the beginning, but I can try to add it and check if it change anything.
**memory** - yes, it's not in the list. I'm thinking, if there could be some problem in timings? As for first look in the table, I have something different in my BIOS. I will return with details after the **swap** test results.

Comment: @kriloleg Your BIOS version F53 is correct for a rev 1 motherboard.

Comment: @kriloleg Do you have your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: @kriloleg Status please...

Comment: Hi @heynnema. Sorry for the delay, I needed some time to finish testing. So, enabling swap didn't help. 

Revision of motherborad is v1.1
BIOS version is F53

Regarding overclock, looks like not. I see many options are set in Auto, XMP is disabled, RAM frequency is 2133Mhz. Regarding RAM timings I couldn't find it in BIOS. But, I see that RAM is in the second slot, maybe would be good to put it into another one: (current: DDR4_B1, available: DDR4_A1)

Comment: Oh, on RAM (physically) there is additional information as: 3000MHz, 16-20-20-38, 1.35V, ver 3.31.

Comment: @kriloleg Please edit your question and show me the current output of `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Then see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @kriloleg I'd suspect power supply, or CPU. Do you have another power supply that you can try?

Comment: Hi @heynnema, I have updated my post with results of the commands You had asked. 
Regarding memetest, being memory in first or second slot it passes well, 4/4. 
Regarding Power Supply, unfortunately - no, I don't have another one to replace and check. Do we have any other options to verify which element is "crashing" ?

Comment: @kriloleg Do `cat /var/log/syslog` and upload that output to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: here is the output of file `/var/log/syslog` : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wNT8Np7nNT/
And, one more output where mce was observed from archive `/var/log/dmesg.1.gz`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rf4gt33vTw/

Comment: @kriloleg The syslog info was incomplete. I didn't see anything wrong with either info.

Comment: yes it's always rotating. But, in `dmesg` log you can find MCE errors. And I have done some search in syslog for errors/fails `zcat syslog.6.gz | grep -i -E 'err|error|mce|warn|fail' | grep -i -v -E 'docker|network|containerd'` maybe can be helpful: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3YFMnsx3dD/, and here is the full output https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5yTV72KTpy/. This log has most of the *errors* information among others.

Comment: @kriloleg I've reviewed the two logs. I don't see MCE errors, only that the monitor is enabled. I DO see LOTS of Docker errors. What's with that? Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Do you have any other RAM that you can try?

Comment: check `dmesg.1.gz` log that I have shared before. It has MCE error. But, it's not anyhow reflected in `syslog`. With dockers interfaces I can share a bit later. Regarding RAM, unfortunately I don't have another one to test. I will ask around to get one for test purpose.

Comment: @kriloleg Have we tried booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB/DVD? I think you have a hardware problem. Take it to a service center. There they can try a different power supply, CPU, or RAM. Report back.

Comment: looks like taking it to a service center is just one possible option to discover the problem. Thanks for the comments, let me try this and report you back.